# Bootstrap .nav-pills active

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Tenho o código, que ao clicar em outro link abre a página e adiciona a classe `.active` já testei vários scripts e nada funciona.

```
<nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>/about">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>/error">Erro</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Quando clicar em sobre ou em erro, queria remover a classe `active` do **inicio** e adicionar ao link clicado. Como fazer?

```js
$(document).on('click','.nav-link', function() {
       $(this).closest('.nav-pills').find('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       return true;
   });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="header clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="home">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="error">Erro</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Title Brand</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```

Ele até troca mas volta a classe `active` pro `Início`. Alguém me da uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percorra os elementos `'li'`, remova classname `'active'` do anterior, e defina para o atual.

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link',function() {
    $(this).closest('.nav-pills').find('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Mas se sua navegação é com refresh, você vai precisar passar algum parametro na url para ser identificado no outro lado e marcar o elemento relacionado como `'active'`.

Fazendo com php:

Supomos que sua url fica assim depois de clicar:

http://localhost/mvc/index.php?pagina=sobre

Ficaria assim:

```
<?php
$pg = $_GET['pagina'];
?>
<nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link <?php if($pg == 'sobre') echo 'active' ?>" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>/about">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link <?php if($pg == 'erro') echo 'active' ?>" href="<?php echo Url::url_base(); ?>/error">Erro</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: funcionou mas a classe active volta pra inicio

Comment: Teria como me ajudar? fiz algumas modificações mas não adiantou.

Comment: coloquei um `return false`, agora trava no .nav-link clicado, porém a URL não funciona.

Comment: Você está fazendo a navegação com ajax ou com refresh ?

Comment: por get, na verdade usando MVC que eu montei pra estudo.

Comment: Mas o disparo desses links, faz o que ? ele atualiza a pagina, ou carrega o conteúdo em uma div sem atualizar?

Comment: Ele atualiza a página, não utilizo ajax

Comment: Então no caso, é melhor fazer com php, como que fica sua url depois de clicar no link ? Pra eu saber como atualizar a resposta.

Comment: ela fica assim: `localhost/mvc/about` por exemplo, aí tem este também `localhost/mvc/erro`, tentei fazer com $_GET mas como estou usando MVC fica muito feio, acho que javascript é a melhor solução porém não consigo.

Comment: Sem fazer a navegação com ajax você não vai conseguir fazer isso com javascript/jQuery, você vai precisar dos parâmetros na URL pra identificar quais são as mudanças e qual é a nova página, e pra fazer a identificação do elemento 'active' pelo parâmetro com php.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo com PHP ?

Comment: Veja a atualização da resposta

Comment: funcionou haha. vlw